# shiny: is it possible to combine updateSliderInput() with a restricted sliding range based on radioButton()?

Tags: r, shiny, uislider, shinyapps

I am producing an `app` that includes a `radioButton()` and `updateSliderInput()`.

The `radioButton()` correspond to whether the patient received radiotherapy `"Yes"/"No"`. The `updateSliderInput` correspond to the radiation dosage received in case of `radioButton=="Yes"`, which ranges between `40` and `60` with `step=0.2`. Logically, if `radioButton=="no"`, the `updateSliderInput==0`. Therefore, the range between `>0` and `<40` must never be accessible to the user.

**Question:** how can I combine (1) `sliderInput==0` if `radioButton=="No"` but (2) `sliderInput==40 to 60` if `radioButton=="Yes"`.

I have pursued a solution with combining a `sliderInput-function`, `observeEvent()` and `updateSliderInput`. However, being completely new, general feedback and other solutions are most welcome.

It is important that values `>0` and `<40` cannot be selected. Therefore, `ticks` and `slider-axis-values` ranging `>0` and `<40` should not be shown on the `sliderInput`

Expected output:
[image]

and

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)



sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
  x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
  x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs, 
                               "data-from-min" = from_min, 
                               "data-from-max" = from_max, 
                               "data-from-shadow" = TRUE)
  x
}


ui <- fluidPage(

  useShinyjs(),

  radioButtons("EXBR", "External Beam Radiation", choiceValues=list("No","Yes"),
               choiceNames=list("No","Yes"), selected ="No", inline=T),
  sliderInput2("EXBRGy", "Cumulative Gy",
               min = 0, max = 60, value = 54.2, step = 0.2, from_min = 40, from_max = 60
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  observeEvent(input$EXBR, {
    if((input$EXBR == "No")){
      disable("EXBRGy")
    }else{
      enable("EXBRGy")
    }
  })


  rvs <- reactiveValues(EXBR = "No")


  observeEvent(input$EXBR, {
    if ((input$EXBR == "No")) {
      updateSliderInput(session, "EXBRGy", value=0)
    }
    rvs$EXBR <- input$EXBR
  })




}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update the slider again, like so:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

sliderInput2 <- function(inputId, label, min, max, value, step=NULL, from_min, from_max){
    x <- sliderInput(inputId, label, min, max, value, step)
    x$children[[2]]$attribs <- c(x$children[[2]]$attribs,
                                 "data-from-min" = from_min,
                                 "data-from-max" = from_max,
                                 "data-from-shadow" = TRUE)
    x
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    useShinyjs(),
    radioButtons("EXBR", "External Beam Radiation", choiceValues=list("No","Yes"),
                 choiceNames=list("No","Yes"), selected ="No", inline=T),
    sliderInput2("EXBRGy", "Cumulative Gy",
                 min = 0, max = 60, value = 54.2, step = 0.2, from_min = 40, from_max = 60
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    rvs <- reactiveValues(prev_value = 54.2)

    observeEvent(input$EXBR, {
        if(input$EXBR == "No"){
            updateSliderInput(session, "EXBRGy",min = 0, max = 0, value=0)
            rvs$prev_value <- input$EXBRGy
            disable("EXBRGy")
        }else{
            updateSliderInput(session, "EXBRGy",  min = 0, max = 60, value = rvs$prev_value)
            enable("EXBRGy")
        }
    })

    observeEvent(input$EXBRGy, {
        print(input$EXBRGy)
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi @PorkChop. Works perfectly. Thank you!